# What does the abbreviation U.FL-LP connector stand for?

Tags: rf, connector, identification, documentation

I am writing up a document on a product that includes some U.FL-LP connectors.  I try to always put the full version of abbreviations when they are first mentioned and I assume U.FL and LP in the U.FL-LP radio frequency (RF) connector names are abbreviations.  Please can anyone tell me what the full name is?

Comment: These seem to just be connector product codes from Hirose. I wouldn't be so sure there is a true "abbreviation". LP does generally mean low-profile or low-power. Looking at some datasheets, it would seem in this case it means low profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U.FL-LP is just the series-name of a particular kind of connector, made by Hirose.

Despite Hirose having patents on those connectors, U.FL compatible connectors can be found from other manufacturers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL).

In the datasheet, there is no indication as to what U.FL stands for. One might try to guess that U stands for micro (as in the μ symbol), LP for low profile, but there is no official indication from Hirose.

Comment: These kind of connectors are called "ultraminiature coaxial connectors", so I suppose that the U might stand for "ultra".

Answer (score 2):

U.FL, as well as W.FL and E.FL are the series name of the connector. X.FL-R-SMT (where X is one of the letters EUW) is the corresponding receptacle (surface-mounted), and X.FL-LP is the part name of a cable assembly with a single corresponding plug. There are also X.FL-2LP cables, which have plugs on both sides.

So my understanding is that R stands for "receptacle" and P stand for "plug".

Official documentation doesn't provide a full name for these connectors.